# UICollectionViewLayout and method layoutAttributesForItem is never called

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewlayout, flowlayout

I am trying to implement a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or `UICollectionViewLayout` - any ways the `layoutAttributesForItem` is never called.

I can see from others that they call `layoutAttributesForItem` from `self.layoutAttributesForItem`.

Like [this flowout](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch08p466collectionViewFlowLayout2/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/MyFlowLayout.swift) example:

I have created a [Playground](https://github.com/JCzz/CollectionView) project you can look at. Overall I am just trying to scale up the center view.

Comment: I know it's a very trivial question but I dare ask it. Have you assigned your custom class to the layout of your collectionView correctly?

Comment: Thanks for asking :-) If you have the time, have a look at this Playground: https://github.com/JCzz/CollectionView       Overall I am just trying to scale the View in the center of the screen.

Comment: @ChrisG.I'm having the same problem.  Everything seems fine except "LayoutAttributesForItem" does not fire at all.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: I never found the solution - let me know if you do. I found that the documentation could be better.

Comment: Has anyone here figured out any solution around this issue?

Answer (score 7):

> Try to use it by Sub-Classing  UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
let flowLayout = LeftAgignedFlowLayout()
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 18
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
self.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout



class LeftAgignedFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {        

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let arr = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!
        return arr.map {
            atts in 

            var atts = atts
            if atts.representedElementCategory == .cell {
                let ip = atts.indexPath
                atts = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at:ip)!
            }
            return atts
        }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        var atts = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at:indexPath)!
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            return atts 

        }
        if atts.frame.origin.x - 1 <= self.sectionInset.left {
            return atts 

        }
        let ipPv = IndexPath(item:indexPath.row-1, section:indexPath.section)
        let fPv = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at:ipPv)!.frame
        let rightPv = fPv.origin.x + fPv.size.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing
        atts = atts.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        atts.frame.origin.x = rightPv
        return atts
    }

}
```

Comment: So what you really proposing here is that we call `layoutAttributesForItem(at:)` ourselves instead of relying the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and expect it to callback? :/

Comment: @MohammadAbdurraafay yes, also if we are using custom flowlayout then it will call this override func.

Comment: This is the best example on the Internet (that I can find) of layoutAttributesForItem in swift.

Comment: It's not a solution anyway, but subclassing FlowLayout didn't change anything.

Comment: @alekop check out my solution, hope it helps.